# Using SQL to calculate GPA , getting "Invalid Identifier" error

Tags: sql, identifier

I'm trying to calculate the GPA of each student in between 4 tables:

```
Student(STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_LNAME, STUDENT_FNAME, MAJOR)
Course(COURSE_NO, COURSE_NAME, DEPT_CODE, CREDITS)
Grade(COURSE_NO, STUDENT_ID, GRADE)
Grade-point(GRADE, POINTS)
```

This is the code I've written:

```
    SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_LNAME, S.STUDENT_FNAME, 
    SUM(C.CREDITS*P.POINTS)/SUM(C.CREDITS) AS GPA
    FROM GRADE_POINT P, STUDENT S, COURSE C, GRADE G
    WHERE S.STUDENT_ID=G.STUDENT_ID
    AND C.COURSE_NO=G.COURSE_NO
    AND G.GRADE=P.GRADE
    GROUP BY S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_LNAME, S.STUDENT_FNAME, GPA;
```

I haven't been taught yet the CREATE PROCEDURE query, therefore I'm not supposed to use it at this level. However, the code doesn't work. It says GPA is an invalid identifier. I honestly can't tell how it's wrong. I also tried removing as many functions as possible for the variable, like this:

```
    SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_LNAME, S.STUDENT_FNAME, (C.CREDITS*P.POINTS) AS 
    TOT_CR_PT, SUM(C.CREDITS) AS TOT_CREDIT, (TOT_CR_PT/TOT_CREDIT) AS GPA
```

But the problem still exists with GPA. What's the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: First, remove the `GPA` from the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to be grouping by GPA, as this is the alias you've given to the `SUM()` Aggregate that you've applied to the set that you have grouped on (Student). Just remove it from the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_LNAME, S.STUDENT_FNAME, 
SUM(C.CREDITS*P.POINTS)/SUM(C.CREDITS) AS GPA
FROM GRADE_POINT P, STUDENT S, COURSE C, GRADE G
WHERE S.STUDENT_ID=G.STUDENT_ID
AND C.COURSE_NO=G.COURSE_NO
AND G.GRADE=P.GRADE
GROUP BY S.STUDENT_ID, S.STUDENT_LNAME, S.STUDENT_FNAME;
```

One other point which might get you marks is to use `JOIN` instead of (ab)using the WHERE clause (recent versions of Oracle do support this syntax):

```
FROM STUDENT S 
     INNER JOIN GRADE G
     ON S.STUDENT_ID=G.STUDENT_ID
...
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that everything I had in SELECT, including the aggregate was supposed to be part of GROUP BY.

Comment: All *non-aggregate* columns specified in the SELECT must be specified in the GROUP BY. But you want the *aggregated* columns to be 'Folded' by the `GROUP BY`, viz to Apply `SUM(.calc.)` across all rows in each `distinct` grouping.